# Adding soap header in client using soap module in node.js

Tags: xml, node.js, soap, salesforce

I am very new to salesforce and trying to create a SOAP client that will connect and fetch details from the salesforce for a particular lead.

I am consuming partner wsdl.

As of now I am able to create client using the partner wsdl.

I have set the session header as given in [this](http://enreeco.blogspot.in/2013/11/nodejs-salesforce-soap-ws-how-to.html)

However when I am trying to fetch some information it's giving me error related to the session header

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sf="urn:fault.partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>sf:INVALID_SESSION_ID</faultcode>
         <faultstring>INVALID_SESSION_ID: Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal Session</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <sf:UnexpectedErrorFault xsi:type="sf:UnexpectedErrorFault">
               <sf:exceptionCode>INVALID_SESSION_ID</sf:exceptionCode>
               <sf:exceptionMessage>Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal Session</sf:exceptionMessage>
            </sf:UnexpectedErrorFault>
         </detail>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am setting the session header like this

```
var sheader = {
                        SessionHeader : {
                            sessionId: result.result.sessionId
                        }
                    };

                    client.addSoapHeader(sheader);
```

I am using [soap](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap) node module for creating the SOAP client, which says the session header to be set like [this](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap#clientaddsoapheadersoapheader-name-namespace-xmlns---add-soapheader-to-soapheader-node).

Now my question is from where can I get these three optional information i.e.

- **name** Unknown parameter (it could just a empty string)
- **namespace** prefix of xml namespace
- **xmlns** URI

Any guidance will be helpful here considering I am fairly new to SOAP and Salesforce.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace this `client.addSoapHeader(sheader,"","tns","");`
with

```
client.addSoapHeader(sheader,"","tns","urn:partner.soap.sforce.com");
```

Comment: Good to know that :)